# Android - Locale Changer

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am experiencing a weird behavior about changing `Locale`. Everything was working fine for every `Android API levels`.
Trying to change the `Locale` of my app but it is not working anymore. 
Everything seems to works fine when setting new `Locale -> AttachBaseContext -> Recreate Activity`, but in the ends i see only strings from `English`.

What recommendations do you give or this may be something wrong with latest `Android Studio 3.5 Canary 9` ?

This is my Custom Context Wrapper :

```
class MyContextWrapper(base: Context) : ContextWrapper(base) {
    companion object {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        fun wrap(contextt: Context, newLocale: Locale): ContextWrapper {
            var context = contextt
            val res = context.resources
            val configuration = res.configuration
            when {
                VersionUtils.isAfter24 -> {
                    configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
                    val localeList = LocaleList(newLocale)
                    LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)
                    configuration.locales = localeList
                    context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
                }
                VersionUtils.isAfter17 -> {
                    configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
                    context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
                }
                else -> {
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    configuration.locale = newLocale
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.displayMetrics)
                }
            }
            return ContextWrapper(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a reported bug on Androidx 1.1.0, find the solution here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140988416#comment6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in `AppCompat 1.1.0-alpha03` , finally it is solved with the latest alpha `AppCompat 1.1.0-alpha04` .

It takes me 3 days and half to understand what's was going wrong because of to many refactoring before notice this behavior.

This happen when you are `early alpha tester` !

As suggestion because this happened before to me (different bug), just be sure to test all the features that you are using when updating to another alpha before continuing to improve and refactor the app. :) :)